# In paint.net, how to configure the coordinate system to have it's origin to the center of my image?

Tags: paint.net

When openning an image with paint.net, the origin of the coordinate system is in the top left corner.

I want it to be at the center of my image:

[image]

- Is it possible. If yes, how ?

Edit:

I have to get some coordinates on this image, with the (0,0) point being on the center of the image. Using paint.net seemed to be a good idea to get it fast.

Comment: You should reveal the benefits of such coordinate system. I'm afraid it would stay difficult to get as long you are the only one who wants it.

Comment: @BradWurst Edited the question.

Comment: "Some coordinates" is a finite list. You can make a spreadsheet (Excel or freeware) which subtracts from every X coordinate the X-coordinate of your midpoint pixel and from every Y coordinate the Y-coordinate of your midpoint pixel. Or reversely adds the midpoint coordinates if you already have your coordinates in zero-in-the-middle -format. I guess it's far easier than making a "show converted coordinates" - plugin. Accepted plugin programmers can get data how to link a plugin, but the full source code of paint.NET is not freely available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use paint.net.  However, if you can't change the origin (which I suspect you probably can't), then it doesn't really matter. You can just use a calculator to work out the true co-ordinates with reference to the origin being in the centre.

So, let's say you have an image which is 100px wide in the x direction, by 200px high in the y direction, and you you want to place something at x=10, y=-20 position in your centre origin co-ordinate system, where 0,0 is the centre of the image, here's how you can work it out the true co-ordinates:

```
x = 100/2 + 10 = 60
y = 200/2 + -20 = 80
```